# Is it possible to use GNOME Terminal's keyboard mnemonics on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity?

Tags: unity, 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS from *mini.iso* with `ubuntu-unity-desktop` meta-package. So I have Unity desktop.

I used GNOME Terminal for years in previous Ubuntu versions. It have keyboard shortcuts (or mnemonics for *F*ile, *E*dit, *V*iew, *S*earch, *T*erminal, *H*elp items of menu bar).

My favorite is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> as shortcut for *Terminal→Reset and c**l**ear*.

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the setting was located in *Edit*→*Preferences*→*General* tab

> [v] Enable mnemonics (such as Alt+F to open the File menu)

or set manually by

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/mnemonics-enabled 'true'
```

but I can't find such option on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity:

> [image: GNOME Terminal on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity]

Setting this option with `dconf` does not help either, terminal does not react on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

What should I do with GNOME Terminal to enable mnemonics on Unity?